# Remove anchor from url - add string to url - and append anchor at the end again

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, anchor

I'm searching for a jquery solution that converts the following URL:

http://www.mysite.com/longpage.html#title3

into

http://www.mysite.com/longpage.html?var=1#title3

Simply adding the "?var=1" is no problem. But the anchor only works when it's placed at the end of the URL.

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Didn't get any further then "$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?var=1');".  I'm no programmer :)

Answer (score 3):

From what you're describing in your question, a simple replace will do the trick:

```
"http://www.mysite.com/longpage.html#title3".replace(/(#.+?)$/, '?var=1$1')
```

It's just plain JS because that's all that's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var href = window.location.href;
if(href.indexOf("#") > 0){
    href = href.split("#")[0] + "?var=1#" + href.split("#")[1];
    window.location.href = href;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/2LhDt/)

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
var urlParts = location.href.split("#");;
var newUrl = urlParts[0]+"?var="+someVar+(urlParts.length>1?"#"+urlParts[1]:"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all.

We implemented yet another solution that was suggested:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
var pos = url.indexOf('#');
if (pos != -1) {
        var newurl = url.substr(0,pos);
        var fragment = url.substr(pos, url.length - pos); 
}
else {
        var newurl = url;
        var fragment = ''; 
}

$(this).attr('href', newurl + '?var=1' + fragment);
```